# Looking for an array formula to count number of times a person enrolled as of their enrollment date for Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, count, array-formulas

I am needing to count each time a person enrolls based on their enrollment date.  It should only count the number a times a person is enrolled for that instance and any previous enrollments.  See graph below for desired outcome.

[image]

My actual file has data starting on row 4 as 1-3 contains data header information.  I continuously add new individuals at the end of the list, however, I do occasionally sort the information so the date needs to be accounted for somehow in case they are not in chronological order.

I tried =Arrayformula({"Number Times Enrolled";if(A4:A="",,countif($A4:A,(Row($A4:A)&"<="&Row($A4:A))))}) but that resulted in 0's for each row.

I tried =Arrayformula({"Number Times Enrolled";if(A4:A="",,countifs(A4:A,A4:A,Row(A4:A),"<="&Row(A4:A)))}) and got 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, blank, blank as a result in column C.

Comment: whats the expected output when the dates are in **not sorted** way? lets say *ID_123_July8* enrolled row comes below to *ID_123_July15* row in your sample dataset...

Comment: The expected outcome would be the same if it was in chronological order.  The count should only count the current enrollment and any previous enrollment based on the date.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/yhzVYWw.png Here's a snapshot of the part I am not clear about. As you can see ID123 has unsorted dates as such & in that scenario should we go with expected_1 output or 2nd one?!

Comment: I see what you mean now...thanks for the image.  I'd expect the second option.  Where the third date of enrollment would be counted as "3" even though it is not in chronological order.

The formula should look through the entire list for the ID and then compare the enrollment dates to see if it should be counted.

Answer (score 0):

*Can you test this one out:*

```js
=map(A4:A,B4:B,lambda(Σ,Λ,if(Σ="",,xmatch(Λ,sort(filter(B:B,A:A=Σ)))+(countif(index(A4:Σ&B4:Λ),Σ&Λ)-1))))
```

[image]